# How to know whether my program is being execute manually or by cron or from another script

Tags: linux, perl

My question is stated in the title:

> How can I discover whether my program is being execute manually or by cron or from another script, and what account is being used?

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the parent PID with `getppid`.

Then finding the parent process name from its PID is non-portable. On linux/unix you could run the `ps` command and parse the output.  On Windows you'll probably need something like `Win32::Process::List`.  No idea for OSX or other operating systems, try Googling *perl get process name from pid*.

Comment: I know the how to get he process by perl. So you mean the concept here is that, if the perl script is being executed by a system, its executed by a parent like the crond? else, its manually executed right? Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to figure out what means what on your system but that's the right idea.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am running a lot of my scripts on linux os. And your concept really helped, is simple and effective. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DigimonDigitizer2: *"I forgot to mention I am running a lot of my scripts on linux os"* If you realise that you have missed some important information from your question then you should add it there. Stack Overflow is intended as a corpus of answers to programming questions, and your question's usefulness to others is more important than whether you get a solution yourself. In this case it's sufficient just to add the Linux tag, which I have done for you